# react on rails / react intl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-intl, react-on-rails

I am trying to implement i18n for a rails/react_on_rails project following this guide;
https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/blob/master/docs/basics/i18n.md

I get the error "formatMessage is not defined", so I am probably missing something, here is my code:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

import { addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
import nb from 'react-intl/locale-data/nb';
import { translations } from '../../../libs/i18n/translations';
import { defaultLocale } from '../../../libs/i18n/default';

// Initizalize all locales for react-intl.
addLocaleData([...en, ...nb]);

// set locale and messages for IntlProvider.
// const locale = method_to_get_current_locale() || defaultLocale;
const locale = defaultLocale;
const messages = translations[locale];

import { defaultMessages } from '../../../libs/i18n/default';


export default class TextMessage extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <IntlProvider locale={locale} key={locale} messages={messages}>   
        { formatMessage(defaultMessages.ActionsYes) }
      </IntlProvider>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the exact error message:

> formatMessage is not defined

I've been using `react-intl` so what I believe you need to do is first to inject `intl` object. You can read about it in the `react-intl` documentation. Try this:

```
import { IntlProvider, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

...

class TextMessage extends React.Component {


  render() {

    return (
      <IntlProvider locale={locale} key={locale} messages={messages}>
        { this.props.intl.formatMessage(defaultMessages.ActionsYes) }
      </IntlProvider>

    );
  }
}

export default injectIntl(TextMessage);
```

I bet it will work.

Or even simpler just change this:

```
import { IntlProvider, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

...

export default class TextMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <IntlProvider locale={locale} key={locale} messages={messages}>
        <FormattedMessage {...defaultMessages.ActionsYes} />
       </IntlProvider>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Small followup here, using the last version I get an error again; Failed prop type: The prop `id` is marked as required in `FormattedMessage`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: You need to pass `id` and `defaultMessage` prop to `FormattedMessage`. make `console.log(defaultMessages.ActionsYes)` and check if it has them.